# Can't get trivial Sveltekit, Tabulator app working

Tags: sveltekit, tabulator

When I try to add a simple Tabulator component to the Sveltekit starter app, the page flashes on screen without the table, then I get "500 Internal Error". I don't know how to debug this.

My TabulatorTable.svelte:

```
<script>
   
  import pkg from 'tabulator-tables';
  const {Tabulator} = pkg;

  import {onMount} from 'svelte';

  export let data, columns;

  let tableComponent;
  onMount(() => {
    new Tabulator(tableComponent, {
      data: data, //link data to table
      reactiveData: true, //enable data reactivity
      columns: columns, //define table columns
    });
  });
</script>

<div bind:this="{tableComponent}"></div>
    
<svelte:head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.4.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</svelte:head>
```

My +page.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Tabulator from './Tabulator.svelte'
    let columns = [
        {title: "One", field: "One"},
        {title: "Two", field: "Two"},
        {title: "Three", field: "Three"},
        {title: "Four", field: "Four"},
        {title: "Five", field: "Five"}
    ]
    let data = [
        {One: "One", Two: "Two", Three: "Three", Four: "Four", Five: "Five"a}
    ]
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Svelte demo app" />
</svelte:head>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<br>
<TabulatorTable columns="{columns}" data="{data}" />
```

Comment: Can you edit the question with the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The import is wrong. This is not the same as importing a named export, you are trying to destructure the *default export*, which does not exist.

It should just be:

```js
import { Tabulator } from 'tabulator-tables';
```

If you still get errors, the package is probably not server-side rendering compatible and you need to use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) in the browser (e.g. in `onMount`).

Regarding debugging, for server errors you have to check the console output of the Vite development server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The change you suggested for the import line does not fix it. Would it be possible for you or someone else to provide modifications to my code that will get this working, or point me to an example? As far as I can tell, there is no working example of Sveltekit + Tabulator posted anywhere.

Comment: If you want help, you have to be more specific; add any error details to the question as already requested by Phix. Also, as noted, changing the import alone may not fix things if you have SSR and the package is incompatible.